# Child view height match scrollview parent height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a scrollview which have two views as children, and i want the one at the end to match the scrollview height not to be fixed.

Currently this what am having:

[image]

The yellow square is the child view and the blue is the parent scroll view.

And the constraints i have for the view is:

[image]

How can i fix this and make the view take the remaining of the scrollview, tried to make the height =< and => but it didn't work too. Also i tried to remove it and still no luck.

Comment: Then what about another child view? How are the constraints handled for that?

Comment: @PGDev the other view is okay, the problem with this at the bottom only

Comment: @Lama - not quite clear... You have a scroll view with two subviews... You're setting the height of one subview, and you want the second subview to fit the remaining vertical space... so it doesn't scroll?

Comment: @DonMag yes exactly

Comment: @Lama - if you want to **prevent** scrolling, why put the views in a scroll view?

Comment: @DonMag because the second view is not taking the remaining height of the screen and in some small screens it was cutted so i added it them in scrollview

Comment: @Lama try embedding the two views inside the stack view

Comment: @Lama - still a little confusing. In the image you show, there is a scrollView with blue background, and ONE subview with yellow background. Can you show a couple images of how you ***want*** the result to look?